# Removing div's and keep content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove the following DIV's:

```
<div class="whatever_name">
   <div class="whatever_name">
      <h2>subtitle</h2> 
      <p>content<p>
   </div>
</div>
```

and need the following output:

```
      <h2>subtitle</h2> 
      <p>content<p>
```

Using jQuery, I can not use remove() because it clear the content too. With pure javascript, happens the same.

I have no idea how to accomplish this issue.

Any idea?

EDIT:

Not always the structure is the same. It can vary, i.e.:

```
<div class="whatever_name">
   <div class="whatever_name">
      <div class="whatever_name">
         <h2>subtitle</h2> 
         <p>content<p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Just need an iterator that can handle such task.

Comment: You want to remove from `content` or from `post-12`...btw I didn't downvote.

Comment: you're going to have to store the children of .post-12 into a temp variable and reference it after removing the divs

Comment: @entio class name can vary in Div's. So, that answer is not correct for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method twice on the children element.

```js
$('.content .post-12')
  //  get children elements, or use contents()
  .children()
  // use unwrap twice to unwrap two parents
  .unwrap().unwrap()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="post-12">
    <h2>subtitle</h2>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** With the updated content you just need to change the selector with your requirement.

```js
$('div > div > h2,div > div > p').unwrap().unwrap()

// or use 
// $('div > div:has(h2):has(p) > *')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whatever_name">
  <div class="whatever_name">
    <div class="whatever_name">
      <h2>subtitle</h2>
      <p>content
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Although firstly i do not know class names, your solution is valid because I can iterate over divs. I did not know the unwrap function. Thanks!